# Removing label 'WordPress' from the title bar

Tags: customization

Generally on our WordPress blogs, there is a label `WordPress` displayed in the title bar. Does anybody have an idea on how to hide or remove it?

My website is powered by WordPress multisite installation and like many people I wanted it as self-branded even though I keep a link back to wordpress.org  in the footer.

Is it inappropriate to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about in the admin? Or on the front-end of the website?

Comment: Yes ! On Dashboard . When a user log in to Dashboard ,it appears

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I personaly don't think you should really do this, and I would leave it there if I were you - it is in fact a way to support WordPress, and don't forget you got it for free. ;)

but, if you really want to do it, go to /wp-admin/admin-header.php

and remove `&#8212; WordPress` from this line:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?> &lsaquo; <?php bloginfo('name') ?>  &#8212; WordPress</title>
```

Comment: You should never change a core file. You get problems on updates, maintenance etc.

Comment: this should **NOT** be the accepted answer, us mentioned be @bueltge core files should never be edited directly. As per the "I personally don't think you should really do this," that's not appropriate for this question That's totally irrelevant. If Automatic didn't want you to do it they probably wouldn't have provided a filter to change it, nor released WordPress under GPL

Answer (score 14):

You're so ashamed to be using WordPress? :-)

---

There's a filter in WP 3.1:

```
$admin_title = apply_filters( 'admin_title', $admin_title, $title );
```

Comment: Why would I fell ashamed ?

Comment: I am using wordpress as  Multisite installation .So when a user log into Dashboard as shown in the above image .
I want to appear the title as Profile< mysite < Dash board Administration.

And it is  Multisite installation ,many people wanted it as self branded at title ,we give link back to wordpress as "Powered by wordpress" at footer. 
I don't know what is wrong in my question

Comment: Oh nothing's wrong with the question. It was just a friendly tease. :-) Editing my answer with the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you but first you must create a child theme of your main theme. Then create `functions.php` file in the child theme and paste this code and you are good to go.

```
   add_filter('admin_title', 'my_admin_title', 10, 2);

function my_admin_title($admin_title, $title)
{
        return get_bloginfo('name').' &bull; '.$title;
}
```

Comment: Putting this in a plugin instead of theme's `functions.php` is better for multisite, where possibly, multiple themes may be used.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can tell, by default Wordpress displays the Blog Title (*Settings->General*). Have you changed that to something besides the default?

Comment: It appears for every blog by default .

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_admin_title( $admin_title ) {
    return str_replace( ' &#8212; WordPress', '', $admin_title );
}

add_filter( 'admin_title', 'custom_admin_title' );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it inappropriate to do this ?

No, your looking at the meta title tag, the easiest solution to change this is with an SEO plugin that can alter the meta title tags dynamically or manually. All of the top SEO plugins have this functionality.

Comment: Once I customized it from some core files or theme files .Now I forgot that .Do you have idea how to do it?

Comment: Yet Another Plugin is **not** the easiest solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If *Settings->General* didn't work better login into database (through control panel or http://website_name.com/phpmyadmin) search for `wp-options`and change blogname.

Comment: Please explain how this will solve the issue without breaking other stuff

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one

1. Hide "-WordPress" text in log in page title

```
// Put this in your functions.php file
function custom_login_title( $login_title ) {
return str_replace(array( ' &lsaquo;', ' &#8212; WordPress'), array( ' &lsaquo;', ''),$login_title );
}
add_filter( 'login_title', 'custom_login_title' );
```

2. Hide "-WordPress" text in Admin page title

```
// Put this in your functions.php file
function custom_admin_title( $admin_title ) {
return str_replace(array( ' &lsaquo;', ' &#8212; WordPress'), array( ' &lsaquo;', ''),$admin_title );
}
add_filter( 'admin_title', 'custom_admin_title' );
```

Answer (score -3):

Go to `wp-admin/admin-header.php`. There you will find this code maybe on line 37 to 53.

You can find the keyword "*WordPress*". Use CTRL+F to find the keyword and manually replace it with something that matches your brand name.

```
if ( is_network_admin() ) {
    /* translators: Network admin screen title. %s: Network title. */
    $admin_title = sprintf( __( 'Network Admin: %s' ), esc_html( get_network()->site_name ) );
} elseif ( is_user_admin() ) {
    /* translators: User dashboard screen title. %s: Network title. */
    $admin_title = sprintf( __( 'User Dashboard: %s' ), esc_html( get_network()->site_name ) );
} else {
    $admin_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
}

if ( $admin_title == $title ) {
    /* translators: Admin screen title. %s: Admin screen name. */
    $admin_title = sprintf( __( '%s &#8212; WordPress' ), $title );
} else {
    /* translators: Admin screen title. 1: Admin screen name, 2: Network or site name. */
    $admin_title = sprintf( __( '%1$s &lsaquo; %2$s &#8212; WordPress' ), $title, $admin_title );
}
```

Comment: This is a very, very bad idea. All your work will be gone right after the next update. Never touch core files, use a plugin instead.